# Gemfire 8.2.2 crashed after 3 days

Tags: gemfire, geode

I upgraded to GF 822 recently.
It ran okay for 3 days and crashed with the following error.
myvmware dot com does not have gemfire listed in supported products.
Any help is highly appreciated.

```
[severe 2017/01/13 00:06:50.421 EST locator1 <locator request thread[21]> tid=0x2ee7] Exception in processing request from X.X.X.X com.gemstone.gemfire.SerializationException: Could not create an instance of  com.gemstone.org.jgroups.stack.GossipData .
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.InternalDataSerializer.readDataSerializable(InternalDataSerializer.java:2521)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.InternalDataSerializer.basicReadObject(InternalDataSerializer.java:2921)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.DataSerializer.readObject(DataSerializer.java:3219)
        at com.gemstone.org.jgroups.stack.tcpserver.TcpServer$3.run(TcpServer.java:356)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: com.gemstone.gemfire.SerializationException: Could not create an instance of  com.gemstone.org.jgroups.stack.GossipData .
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.InternalDataSerializer.invokeFromData(InternalDataSerializer.java:2493)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.InternalDataSerializer.readDataSerializable(InternalDataSerializer.java:2509)
        ... 6 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor242.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.InternalDataSerializer.invokeFromData(InternalDataSerializer.java:2468)
        ... 7 more Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
        at com.gemstone.org.jgroups.stack.IpAddress.fromData(IpAddress.java:705)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.InternalDataSerializer.invokeFromData(InternalDataSerializer.java:2480)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.DSFIDFactory.create(DSFIDFactory.java:1080)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.InternalDataSerializer.basicReadObject(InternalDataSerializer.java:2797)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.DataSerializer.readObject(DataSerializer.java:3219)
        at com.gemstone.org.jgroups.stack.GossipData.fromDataPre_GFE_8_0_0_0(GossipData.java:196)
```

Comment: I am running once cache server, 1 locator and 1 pulse instance, 10 application layer members are connected to the cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems your client is having a different version of Gemfire? Can you check the loaded version of gemfire jar in client, they are likely from GF 6 generation.